# Error when creating dataframe using dplyr in loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with all numeric variables and one `date` variable. For each variable `VARIABLE` I want to create a dataframe using the following dplyr code:

```
avg_price = full_data_noNO %>% 
group_by(Month, Country) %>%
dplyr::summarize(avg = mean(VARIABLE, na.rm = TRUE))
```

This works fine if I hard code the name `VARIABLE` but if I do it in a loop I get the warning `In mean.default(data.matrix(VARIABLE), na.rm = TRUE) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`. As a result the average column in my `avg_price` dataframe only contains NA's. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Update:
I currently have a function:

```
make_plots_expl_vars <- function (VARIABLE, full_data_noNO ) {
   avg_price = full_data_noNO %>% 
   group_by(Month, Country) %>%
   dplyr::summarize(avg = mean(VARIABLE, na.rm = TRUE))
   return(avg_price)
```

Which I call using for example `make_plots_expl_vars("price", full_data_noNO)`. I want to call this function for all variables in my dataframe using a loop, but I know how to do that.

Comment: Could you please show the loop code which fails with this error ? It will be easier to help you with it.

Comment: If you're iterating over all columns in your data.frame (other than Month/Country) you might gain from using summarize_if(is.numeric, mean) or summarize_all(mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `rlang::sym` or `rlang::enquo`.

With `rlang::sym`:

```
make_plots_expl_vars <- function (VARIABLE, data=full_data_noNO) {
  xx = sym(VARIABLE)
  avg_price = data %>% 
    group_by(Month, Country) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(avg = mean(!!xx, na.rm = TRUE))
  return(avg_price)
}
make_plots_expl_vars("price", full_data_noNO)
make_plots_expl_vars("price") #you don't need it anymore with the "data" argument
```

With `rlang::enquo`:

```
make_plots_expl_vars <- function (VARIABLE, data=full_data_noNO) {
  xx = enquo(VARIABLE)
  avg_price = data %>% 
    group_by(Month, Country) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(avg = mean(!!xx, na.rm = TRUE))
  return(avg_price)
}
make_plots_expl_vars(price, full_data_noNO)
```

The difference is that in one case you declare your variable with quotes and in the other without. Your variable is then unquoted inside `dplyr` functions with the `!!` operator. If you want more information, you can take a look at [the quasiquotation doc](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html) or at the ["Programming with dplyr" tuto](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr/vignettes/programming.html).

Note that `rlang` is already included in `dplyr` so you don't have to import the library.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have been looking for days for this solution and now it finally works!